# Javascript case (true) throwing Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, switch-statement, syntax-error

When I run the code below on Chrome, the console shows an `Unexpected identifier` exception.

```
var a = true;
var b = false;

switch (true) {
  a:
    window.alert('test A');
    break;
  b:
    window.alert('test B');
    break;
  default:
    window.alert('test C');
}
```

I tried to run the code directly on console to guarantee the error is not caused by other line on my script, but I'm still receiving the exception.

I also looked for an answer through Google, but didn't found any answer for this strange behaviour.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can't write `b:` you must write `case b:`

```
var a = true;
var b = false;

switch (true) {
  case a:
    window.alert('test A');
    break;
  case b:
    window.alert('test B');
    break;
  default:
    window.alert('test C');
}
```